# How can I seperate digits a given integer with C++?

Tags: c++

Can you help me please? I try to do with while statement but I could not write the program.

Given an integer for example 12564897 and the program must show it 1-2-5-6-4-8-9-7

How do you detect in C++. Thanks a lot.

I tried with five digits integer.

```
int z,y,x,result,number1,number2,number3,number4,number5;
cout<<"Enter a five digit integer: ";
cin>>result; //read number

cout<<"The number is: "<<result<<endl;

number1 = result / 10000;

x = result / 1000;
number2 = x % 10;

y = result / 100;
number3 = y % 10;

z = result / 10;
number4 = z % 10;

number5 = result % 10;

cout<<"digits are: "<<number1<<"-"<<number2<<"-"<<number3<<"-"<<number4<<"-"<<number5<<endl;

system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What have you tried? Show us some code, tell us what's your concept for doing that.

Comment: Post what you have tried so far, else the experienced developers on these groups may conclude that you are just using us to do your entire homework assignment.  There are couple of approaches - stringify the number and split char-by-char or your can use iterative/recursive divisions by 10.

Comment: I tried with 5 digits number.

Comment: int z,y,x,result,number1,number2,number3,number4,number5;
    
     cout<<"Enter a five digit integer: ";
     cin>>result; 
    
    cout<<"The number is: "<<result<<endl;
         
    number1 = result / 10000;
    
    x = result / 1000;
    number2 = x % 10;
    
    y = result / 100;
    number3 = y % 10;
    
    z = result / 10;
    number4 = z % 10;
    
    number5 = result % 10;
    
    cout<<"digits are: "<<number1<<"-"<<number2<<"-"<<number3<<"-"<<number4<<"-"<<number5<<endl;
    
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}

Comment: Not one recursive solution so far...

Comment: @martinJames: Nor even a stringstream!

Answer (score 4):

I think the smartest way is create a loop that divide by ten ( or the base ) and print the remainder, then divide by ten and do again. In preudo code:

```
let a = input
let base = 10
do
{
     store a mod base in result
     a = (integer) a / base;
}while(a>0)
print result reversed
```

mod is the remainder operator `( % in C/C++ )`
please note thad by changing base you can have the digit in any representation of the number

Comment: thanks for your help Felice Pollano and I have tried your given code but I did something wrong because it did not work.        cout<<"Enter an integer: ";
              cin>>result;
              counter = 10;
              while (number > 0)
              {
                 x = result / 10;
                 number = x % 10;       
              }
                  cout<<number<<endl;

Comment: @kubra you can elaborate on it since it is homework, please note also, as stakx stated, the 0 case :)

Comment: felice, cchange the while loop to a do/while loop to handle zero, or to a for loop to handle a specific number of digits

Comment: since you went to the trouble of creating & initializing the variable `base`, you probably also want to change the code to `a = (integer) a / base`

Answer (score 0):

Convert your Integer to a string and then print every character of that string with a `-` in between.

Answer (score 0):

This is snippet from program which print out integer in reverse order.
You can modify it to fits your need (it's your homework)

```
//Read input number
cin >> dInput;
//Calculate log10
int logValue = (int)log10(dInput);

//Iteration through n-th power of 10
for(int i = logValue; i >= 0; i--) {
    //Calculate actual power of 10
    double d = pow(10,(double)i);

    int n = (int)dInput / d;

    //Subtract remainder from previous number
    dInput -= (n * d);

    //Print out "-"
    cout << n;
    if(i != 0) << "-";
}
```

Comment: @David Schwartz, great comment, you have right, this code I posted was created long time ago to demonstrate how decimal number can be decomposed using log10.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about writing the code itself, but since it's a homework, I'll give you the idea and let you code it

First, you'll convert that integer to a string using [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/) function

Then you'll make an integer having the size of the string. Let it be **S**

Then you'll make a for loop,

`i=1, i < S, i+=2`

i starts from 1 as the - is put ***after*** the first character

In that loop, you would insert the ***-*** character at the position of i, then you'll update integer S with the size. If you didn't update it, the following (for example) would happen

```
12345 (size = 5)
1-2345 (size = 5, real size = 6)
1-2-345 (size = 5, real size = 7)
```

It would stop here. As the condition i<5 would fail

That's all. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

OK, since everyone else has had a go, this is my attempt:

```
void outInt(int inInt){
  int dividend;
  dividend=inInt/10;
  if (dividend!=0){
    outInt(dividend);
    cout<<"-"<<inInt%10;
  }
  else
    cout<<(inInt);
};
```

No 'print result reversed' required.  Should work for 0 and not print any '-' for numbers less than 10.